# Oracle subquery will run, but not this entire query

Tags: oracle

The subquery runs fine on its own. But the entire query isn't working. The error I'm getting is `SQL command not properly ended` which is useless. I've tried editing it a hundred times and searched for hints, but can't figure it out...

```
select table_name, sum(has_last_mod_time) as asdf
from 
  (
    select
      table_name,
      case when lower(column_name) = 'last_modified_time' then 1 else 0 end  has_last_mod_time
    from all_tab_columns
  ) 
group by  table_name
) as sdfsdf
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not support using `AS` for a table alias.

Remove the `as` from `as sdfsdf`

But your query has more problems then just that:

You also have one `)` too many and the `group by` is at the wrong place.

```
select table_name, sum(has_last_mod_time) as asdf
from (
    select
      table_name,
      case when lower(column_name) = 'last_modified_time' then 1 else 0 end  has_last_mod_time
    from all_tab_columns
    --<< no ")" here
) sdfsdf --<< no AS here
group by  table_name --<< and the group by needs to go here
```

Comment: @simplycoding - 1. Yes, a_horse is serious. 2. The error message was not "useless" - if you would look at it more closely you would see that it tells you **exactly** where the error was encountered (which is where a_horse told you). 3. That kind of question (your comment to this Answer) will make it less likely that people will want to help you in the future. Remember this is a "free help" web site. If you don't believe an answer, test it before you make smart comments like that - then just say "thank you" after you see it works.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Yes it does, and twice, even. I just typed `select * from dual as a` in my editing window. Even without running the statement, a little red wavy line right after the word `as` shows me I'll be in trouble. Then I ran the statement, and the Query Result tab shows me the error message and the exact position where it occurred. (I use SQL Developer about 90% of the time, so I know!) The other 10% of the time I use SQL\*Plus, which of course tells you everything, and I also used Toad once or twice and it does the same.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - The SQL Developer editor window shows (or can show) line numbers, and it shows where on a line you are. So if the error message says "Error at Line: 1 Column: 20" (as it does), it should be easy to find even without the visual cues. And, in fact, in the editor window there's a little red wavy underline at the spot of the error, too - it's right in the editor, never mind the error message. You can see it in your screenshot! (Except that you chose to make yours pink; mine is red, by choice I made.)